# Pull data from HDFS and Populate website

Tags: html, hadoop, hive, apache-pig, hdfs

I want to know the possible ways of pulling the data from HDFS (Hive tables or normal .txt files on HDFS) and populate the tables on my website (HTML page) ?

Comment: This question seems a little broad -  and asking for a specific tools or libraries is offtopic on this site. Please add some details of what you're trying to achieve or query your favorite search engine with the words `apache` `hadoop` `frontend`...

Comment: I think almost every backend script can fetch data from hdfs/hive table/impala, I have tried it with node.js, and python using thrift library.